# @AssertTrue Method not called when submitting JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, assert, bean-validation

I am using bean validation with hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final and JSF 2.1. When i submit the page `@NotEmpty, @NotNull`,.. works correct , but my method, annotated with `@AssertTrue` is never called.

I changed the access modifier to public, renamed it to getValid, but the method is never called..

```
@AssertTrue(message = "test")
    private Boolean isValid() {
        return ....;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that not all fields are validated by JSF, only those that are in my facelet.

If I call

```
SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeObject>> violations = validator.validate(so);
```

in a test, the isValid method is triggerd.

Answer (score 1):

JSF is not validating a full bean via *Validator#validate*, but rather calls *Validator#validateValue* for each form field. Is this *isValid* a form field?